# How to reset row in php?

Tags: php

i'm trying to execute the flowwing php it works fine for the first time but then i cant reset the row to do it again i did some reasearch and i found the `mysql_data_seek` but it's still working only the first time and printing `mysql_data_seek() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\test\json_pub.php on line 36`

here is the php file help please i cant find the problem

```
 <?php 

$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 

 mysqli_select_db($conn,"bdpfe") or die ("no database");   

 $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"Select nom , prénom ,photo_user, titre_pub ,date_pub , photo, texte ,nbr_vu,p.id_user,p.id_pub,t.id_texte
From user u , publication p , photo ph , texte t 
 where
u.id_user=p.id_user and
p.id_photo = ph.id_photo and
p.id_texte = t.id_texte 
ORDER BY  p.id_pub desc "); 


$response = array();
$pub = array();
$result=$sql;

$sql1=mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from commentaire");
$result1=$sql1;


while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$nbr=0;

while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
{ 
if($row['id_pub']==$row1['id_pub'])
{
$nbr=$nbr+1;
 }

 }
 mysql_data_seek($result1, 0);

 $nom=$row['nom'];
 $prenom=$row['prénom']; 
 $photo_u=$row['photo_user'];
 $titre=$row['titre_pub'];
 $date=$row['date_pub'];
 $photo=$row['photo'];
 $texte=$row['texte'];
 $vu=$row['nbr_vu'];
 $id_u=$row['id_user'];
 $id_p=$row['id_pub'];
 $id_t=$row['id_texte'];
 $nbr_com=$nbr;


 $pub[] = array('nom'=>$nom,'prenom'=> $prenom, 'photo_u'=> $photo_u,'titre'=>$titre,'date'=>$date,'photo'=>$photo,'texte'=>$texte,'vu'=>$vu,'id_u'=>$id_u,'id_p'=>$id_p,'id_t'=>$id_t,'nbr_com'=>$nbr_com);

 } 

 $response['pub'] = $pub;

 echo "mycallback(".json_encode($response).")";


 ?>
```

Comment: You're using `mysql_data_seek()` when your connection is `mysqli_*()`. You cannot mix the APIs - they're not compatible. You need to use  `mysqli_stmt_data_seek()` ([Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php)), but I suspect that what you _really_ need is to rework your queries so that none of  this is necessary.

Comment: hobo is absolutely right here. Good one @HoboSapiens